# www subdomain pings the correct IP address, but directs to the wrong site

Tags: dns, web, traffic, cloudflare

I am in the midst of publishing a new site. When I navigate to the address https://peeltx.com the correct site comes up. When I navigate to https://**www**.peeltx.com I am directed to a site hosted by the domain register. There is a www A-record in the DNS records. When I ping the site through powershell or run it through DNS Checker using [www.peeltx.com](http://www.peeltx.com), the correct IP address is returned. I am trying to identify the issue to figure out how to direct the DNS host support.

The www site is hosted and created at the domain register/name server site (Sitelio), the non-www site is hosted on an external cloudflare server, it feels like the issue must be with the register/name server host instead of the cloudflare web server?

Comment: If the same IP is returned, this is not a DNS problem at all, but instead a web server problem.

Comment: Yes, both DNS addresses are going to the same server (the www site shows peeltx error page, not the registrar). Your webservice may not be configured for the www hostname

Comment: In my ISP's customer menu I can select for every subdomain which base directory to use from my directory tree.

Comment: I must be confused, the www site is hosted and created at the domain register/name server site (Sitelio), the non-www site is hosted on an external cloudflare server, it feels like the issue must be with the register/name server host instead of the cloudflare web server?